# Voting Program Using HashMap with Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Hello so below is the code I have so far but am now stuck on the last little part.  I have gotten everything to be the right values in the HashMap but am unsure how to get the key associated with a specific value.  The keys are a unique identification of the candidate while the value is the total number of votes.

I am pretty sure I have seen online that there is a way to get a 1:1 mapping of key/value so I can retrieve a specific key when I know a certain value but am unsure how to do this.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class VoteCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /** Hardwire values in for Sample Input 1 */

        /** Sample Input 1 */
        int numberVotes1 = 8;
        HashMap<String, Vote> votes1 = new HashMap<String, Vote>(numberVotes1);

        Vote vote1 = new Vote("123456789");
        Vote vote2 = new Vote("111111111");
        Vote vote3 = new Vote("987654321");
        Vote vote4 = new Vote("111111111");
        Vote vote5 = new Vote("987654321");
        Vote vote6 = new Vote("987654321");
        Vote vote7 = new Vote("987654321");
        Vote vote8 = new Vote("987654321");

        castVote(votes1, vote1);
        castVote(votes1, vote2);
        castVote(votes1, vote3);
        castVote(votes1, vote4);
        castVote(votes1, vote5);
        castVote(votes1, vote6);
        castVote(votes1, vote7);
        castVote(votes1, vote8);

        System.out.println(votes1.size());
        System.out.println(votes1.keySet());
        System.out.println(votes1.entrySet());
        System.out.println(votes1.get("123456789"));
        System.out.println(votes1.get("111111111"));
        System.out.println(votes1.get("987654321"));

        /** Sample Input 2 */
        int numberVotes2 = 2;
        HashMap<String, Vote> votes2 = new HashMap<String, Vote>(numberVotes2);

        Vote vote9 = new Vote("123456789");
        Vote vote10 = new Vote("111111111");

        castVote(votes2, vote9);
        castVote(votes2, vote10);

        System.out.println(votes2.size());
        System.out.println(votes2.keySet());
        System.out.println(votes2.entrySet());
        System.out.println(votes2.get("123456789"));
        System.out.println(votes2.get("111111111"));
    }

    public static class Vote {

        private int vote;
        private String voterIdentification;

        public Vote(String s) {
            vote = 1;
            voterIdentification = s;
        }

        /** Create getter/setter for any private variables */
        public int getVote() { return vote; }
        public void setVote(int _vote) { this.vote = _vote; }

        public String getIdentification() { return voterIdentification; }
    }

    /**Method used for casting vote */
    public static void castVote(HashMap _votes, Vote _vote) {
        if(_votes.containsKey(_vote.getIdentification())) {
            int vote = (int) _votes.get(_vote.getIdentification());
            _votes.put(_vote.getIdentification(), vote + 1);
        }
        else {
            _votes.put(_vote.getIdentification(), _vote.getVote());
        }
    }

}
```

Output is as follows (for display purposes to show all values are correct):

```
3
[111111111, 987654321, 123456789]
[111111111=2, 987654321=5, 123456789=1]
1
2
5
2
[111111111, 123456789]
[111111111=1, 123456789=1]
1
1
```

Comment: Why would you need to get the key for a value?

Comment: You are complicating matters considerably by first storing a Vote object as a map value which is then replaced by an Integer count greater than one. Why don't you simply use a `Map<String,Integer>`? Passing a Map without generic parameters around as a method parameter makes your program susceptible for cast errors, and the warnings aren't to be ignored.

Comment: You don't have a 1:1 relationship. One count value may get you any number of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is a dastructure which allows the storage of pair of elements . Each key is associated with a value, however the same value can be mapped to more keys. So the 1:1 mapping is only from key to value. You can't be sure to retrieve a unique key starting from a given value.

Answer (score 0):

"a way to get a 1:1 mapping of key/value" You don't have 1:1, because a certain vote count can be reached by any number of candidates, hence you have n:1. So, if you invert the hash map counting votes, the inverse would have to be `Map<Integer,Set<String>>`. You can create this Map by iterating the EntrySet of the original Map:

```
Map<String,Integer> cand2count = ...;
Map<Integer,Set<String>> count2cands = new HashMap<>();
for( Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry: cand2count.entrySet() ){
     count2cands.computeIfAbsent(entry.getValue(),
                                 k -> new HashSet<String>()).add(entry.getKey());
}
```